# DEPENDENCY INJECTION .NET CORE

Tags: .net-core, dependencies, code-injection

I am sorry to bother you with this question. I was given a simple WEB API task which I have done in Visual Studio 2019 targeting .net core 3.1. My challenge is I was expected to upload this work to a remote server. However, on the remote server, the STARTUP CLASS is set to READ ONLY which means I cannot overwrite it. I used a DEPENDENCY INJECTION in my code and now the code wont run. My question is , is there other way to implement DEPENDENCY INJECTION without altering the START UP CLASS?

Answer (score 0):

Check on the remote server if Program.cs is not read-only then you can add dependencies there.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    //add dependencies here
                    services.AddLogging();
                });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```